# OpenLayers change color of feature on runtime

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, cartography, openlayers-6

I use OpenLayers v6.3.1, including the following stylesheet and script: [Scriptfile](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js), [Stylesheet](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css)

**Goal:**

My goal is to change the color of a feature (LineString) on runtime using javascript.

**Setup:**

I mainly used the code from this website: [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html)

```
var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map', //<div id="map"></div>
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                center: [11.592581, 47.241524],
                zoom: 15
            })
        });
```

In this piece of code I create a line between two coordinates:

```
    var lonlat1 = [11.592581, 47.241524];
    var lonlat2 = [11.58554, 47.248958];
    //create the line's style
    var lineStyle = [
        // linestring
        new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#000',
                width: 2
            })
        })
    ];

    //create the line       
    var line = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [
                new ol.Feature({
                    geometry: new ol.geom.LineString([lonlat1, lonlat2])
                })
            ]
        }),
        style: lineStyle
    });
    map.addLayer(line);
```

Which gives me this map:
[image: Map]

I want to change the color of the line at runtime.

**What I tried so far:**
I tried to change the color using the following code:

```
line.style_[0].stroke_.color_ = '#123';
```

The value of the color did change, but the color of the line itself remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i figured it out. The style can be changed with the setStyle() function which is part of the line object.

```
line.setStyle([
    new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#123',
            width: 2
         })
     })
 ]);
```

This is definitely not the best solution so I am open to anything better.

### EDIT:

As mentioned by @Mike in the comments, `line.getStyle().getStroke().setColor('#123')` works just fine

Comment: Did you try `line.getStyle().getStroke().setColor('#123');`?

Comment: `line.getStyle().getStroke().setColor('#123');` works just fine.